# comparison between Fourier transform and autocorrelation function

Tags: analog-to-digital

If the Fourier Transform of a signal is enough to determine its spectral density, why do we complicate our lives by defining the autocorrelation function?

Comment: Wiener-Kinchin doesn't apply to all possible signals; the Fourier transform isn't even *defined* for all possible stochastic signals.

Comment: Besides, the autocorrelation gives you information that the PSD doesn't.

Comment: @MBaz Huh? What information is there in the autocorrelation function that cannot be determined from the inverse Fourier transform of its power spectral density?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Well, what I was thinking is that WK is true only for stationary processes whose autocorrelation has a FT. I'll grant you that this is a bit pedantic, but the question is quite open-ended.

Comment: @MBaz No pedantism in your comments. Words and theorems are important, esp. when one wants to "not complicate one's life"

Answer (score 4):

Signals can be classified in many ways, and one of them is according to their **nature** such as being **deterministic** or **random** (stochastic). When a signal is deterministic, its spectral content is given by the Fourier transform provided that the signal is absolutely (or square o.w.) integrable; i.e., its Fourier transform exists.

On the other hand when an signal is stochastic, then ideally by definition its Fourier transform does not exist. (a random signal will always have infinite energy as it cannot decay to zero when time goes to infinity because then it will not be random otherwise.)

Therefore for random signals, the Fourier transform will not exist and their spectral density cannot be computed that way. Nevertheless, for such signals an indirect description, based on an autocorrelation measure, can also be defined, whose advantage being that the Fourier transform of it may exist. Therefore the PSD of a random process is defined as the Fourier transform of its ACF.

Comment: Fat32: Is it correct to say that what you described is exactly why there is the whole field called spectral estimation  which focuses on methods for estimating the spectrum when the signal is stochastic. This area is really just a branch of statistics ( see Kundu's "statistical signal processing")  and how I got into finding out about DSP in the first place. Thanks.

Comment: @mark leeds. Yes indeed ! However please note that, electrical engineering borrows subject of stochastic signals from its physical applications such as brownian motion, thermal noise, Boltzman statistics etc. Which is at least different in notation from a purely statistical treatment which may not have any physical concerns.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful explanation. yes, often the apps are not physical but the problem is the same: find the important frequencies !!!!

Comment: Last bother today. Do you know why when I put an ampersand in front of Fat32, it gets disregarded and when you do the same, it doesn't.

Comment: @markleeds I really don't know the true reason. And that happens to me too. For some names that "@" gets lost and for most others it does not. However please note that whether "@" is lost or not, the **comment** is indicated in my mail box... One reason I can hypothesize is that when a comment is automatically send to a user then there is no need to add the name explicitly, such as any comment posted on my answer, you don't need to add my name... may be that's it or may be not. Otherwise I have no idea.

Comment: @markleeds When you're commenting on someone's post, they'll get notified, so no need to (or ability to) @ them. That way you can get at most two notifications generated: the author of the commented-upon post and someone else commenting on it. I don't believe it's possible to @ more than one person.

Comment: Thanks Fat32 and Peter K. The knowledge is appreciated. I also think that I'm not supposed to say thanks but I find it rude not to. All the best.